# How can I adapt hotkeys for ncurses vlc?

Tags: linux, settings, vlc, hotkeys

does anyone know how I can change hotkeys for the ncurses vlc interface nvlc?

Any help is greatly appreciated.. Can't find stuff anywhere somehow??

greetings

Comment: Try editing the `vlcrc` file ( on Linux - $HOME/.config/vlcrc) it will have override entries for most functions.

Comment: ahhh, im stupid. thank you sir